# Stack to Grid UIcollectionView with dynamically changing number of sections

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I am using two subclasses of `UICollectionViewController`, `StackViewController` and `GridViewController`. I am using a stack type gallery at first and then the transition happens when pinching any cell.

In the stack I have 5 albums so I passed `numberofsections` as 5 and then, when the user pinches out, transition to another controller which is using grid layout n then m returning `numberofSections` as 1.

The problem is all other albums in the stack gallery disappear when I pinch because I had set `numberofsections` to 1. I tried to return a different datasource for `UICollectionView` from the different controller but it only uses the `StackViewController` datasource.

Comment: Why does the stack need to be divided into sections? This is going to be a lot easier if your view controllers use the same set of index paths, particularly if you want to animate between the two layouts.

Comment: I want the transition to look similar to iPad gallery transition. what exactly I need to do?